# Show/ Hide div based on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide a div class="axiosnext-arrow" when the current url is www.mysite.com/#home using the following code:

```
<script language="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
        $(function(){
            if (window.location.search == "#home") {
                $('.axiosnext-arrow').hide();
            } else {
                $('#navleft').show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the unexpected behavior?

Comment: @WillP. the div does not disappear

Comment: I don't believe you need the `$` parameter in the function definition, it should already exist at the window level

Comment: @user38208 please make sure `window.location.search` is returning `#home`. I suppose it is returning `home` instead, not sure

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $(function(){
        if (window.location.hash == "#home") {
            $('.axiosnext-arrow').hide();
        } else {
            $('#navleft').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(function(){
        if (window.location.hash == "#home") {
            $('.axiosnext-arrow').hide();
        } else {
            $('#navleft').show();
        }
    });
```

You dont need `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` and `$(function(){`. They do the same thing. `$(function() {` is the short hand version, see [Here.](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using window.location.search you could use window.location.pathname or window.location.href and just search for your substring of #home.

This is where my answer came from:
[Get current URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/get-current-url-in-javascript)

Comment: It would be helpful if  it would be impossible to achieve this using `window.location.search`..

Comment: @RayonDabre i tried using window.location.search but it would not bring in #home, only anything that was a parameter. which is why i suggested to use .href. i actually just tried using .pathname and it would not return the #home. Only when i tried .href did it grab #home.