# How to hide an element if the page contains a specific url / word?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

With JavaScript I'm trying to hide an element that contains a text message when the page URL is my-website.com/login/?lost_pass=1. I managed to hide the tag but it doesn't work as I expected.

The unwanted tag is actually hidden, but the same also happens when the page is my-website.com/login while it should only be hidden if the page is my-website.com/login/?lost_pass=1

So, for example, you are on my-website.com/login, but when you click "lost password" the page reloads to show a different form, so the URL becomes my-website.com/login/?lost_pass = 1

Can anyone help me with this? I don't understand where I'm wrong.

**I tried this, but the tag is hidden on all pages**

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('?lost_pass=1')) {
    //Hide the element.
    document.querySelectorAll('#msg_social')[0].style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

**Then I tried that, but the tag is not hidden in any of the pages**

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("?lost_pass=1") != -1) {
$("#msg_social").hide();
}
```

Comment: i think you need to use : `window.location.href.contains('?lost_pass=1')` instead, that way you don't have to do the `!= -1`. And also -1 will pass the if test, so `if (window.location.href.indexOf('?lost_pass=1'))` will pass all the time

Comment: Tags are text in a file. Elements are what you're attempting to hide.

Comment: Does `#msg_social` exist in the initial render of the page?

Comment: Of course there is ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onload code has a if that always pass :

```
window.onload = function() {
  // this if will always pass, any number will pass that if like -1, 25 etc...
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('?lost_pass=1')) {
    //Hide the element.
    document.querySelectorAll('#msg_social')[0].style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

it's better to use .contains :

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (!window.location.href.includes('?lost_pass=1')) {
    //Hide the element.
    document.querySelectorAll('#msg_social')[0].style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

it's shorter and avoid forgetting about the `!= -1` thing

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it. I'm trying your suggestion but it doesn't work. I'll try to understand if I'm making any mistakes and eventually update the question.

Comment: Do you have any error ? perhaps you need to wait for the element to be in the dom, if it's added dynamically

Comment: Yes, there is actually an error. `Uncaught TypeError: window.location.href.contains is not a function at window.onload (? lost_pass = 1: 847: 28) at window.onload (waypoints.min.js? ver = 4.0.2: 1: 8753)`

Comment: mm it's strange, because it should be a function: `ƒ (e){return this.indexOf(e)>-1}`, what does window.location.href return ? i don't think there is a scenario where href is null, it should always be a string

Comment: I solved, I'm trying with: `window.location.href.match('\\?lost_pass=1'))` and it seems to work. I will accept your answer as the correct one because it led me to the solution, albeit indirectly.

Comment: I think the native method is includes not contains, i have a contains method on the String prototype but it's not a native one, defined here : https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=e6d116cd69f1 i will be more careful when executing code in stackoverflow console ^^

Comment: Ok, this is also working `window.location.href.includes('?lost_pass=1'))` but will it work for all browsers ?

Comment: From chrome 40 so pretty much everyone